# One to many relationship expressed in JSON

Tags: c#, json, linq

I am having a small problem in some LINQ I am writing

```
 public async Task<BookingEntry[]> AuditInvoiceForAPI(BookingSearchFilter filter)
        {
            if (filter == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();

            using var speedPayDbContext = this.speedPayDbContextFactory();
            var results = await speedPayDbContext.spAuditInvoiceForAPI(filter.BookingID, filter.VendorID, filter.InvoiceID).ToArrayAsync();

            var BookingResponse = results
                .Select(r =>
                {
                    return new BookingEntry()
                    {
                        Result = r.Result,
                        BookingID = r.BookingID,
                        Balance = r.Balance,
                        TotalCost = r.TotalCost,
                        CostDetails =

                            results.Where(cd => cd.BookingID == r.BookingID)
                                .Select(a => new Costdetail(a.Amount, a.ChargeCodeID)).ToArray(),
                         
                        Message = r.Message,
                    };
                })
                .ToArray();


            return BookingResponse;
```

here is the result set

| BookingId | Result | Message | TotalCost | BillKey | Balance | ChargeCodeId | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8446670 | 0 | Success | 498.54 | 8446670 | 89.8000 | 11 | 75.00 |
| 8446670 | 0 | Success | 498.54 | 8446670 | 89.8000 | 14 | 14.80 |

I am getting dup in the JSON which I can understand why.  There are indeed two rows returned one booking entry with two costdetails.

Can someone please help me with get rid of the dup?

Its probably as simple as I don't understand SelectMany.

This is in essence a simple join first 6 columns are the header and the last two are the detail records and you can see that the bookingID is what they are joined on.

Thanks very much

```
  {
    "bookingID": "8446670",
    "result": "0",
    "message": "Success",
    "totalCost": 498.54,
    "balance": 89.8,
    "costDetails": [
      {
        "chargeCodeID": 11,
        "amount": 75
      },
      {
        "chargeCodeID": 14,
        "amount": 14.8
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "bookingID": "8446670",
    "result": "0",
    "message": "Success",
    "totalCost": 498.54,
    "balance": 89.8,
    "costDetails": [
      {
        "chargeCodeID": 11,
        "amount": 75
      },
      {
        "chargeCodeID": 14,
        "amount": 14.8
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: `GroupBy(r => r.BookingID).Select(g => g.First())` ?

Comment: That did it do you want to post an answer so I can give you credit

Comment: I still can't help wonder if I am doing something in a less optimal way.